# Extract javascript variable from big HTML file

Tags: javascript, ruby, regex

I have a giant source file in HTML with javascript I'd like to extract some information from a javascript content. Considering I have a file like the following

```
<h1>Hello World</h1>
<script type="text/javascript">something useless</script>
<script type="text/javascript">var gmaps_vars = {FullAddress: "Rio de Janeiro, Rio de Janeiro, Brasil", GeoLocation: {"lng":-43.187554,"lat":-22.9470974}}</script>
```

How would I extract the latitude and longitude?

Comment: What do you mean fetch the var?

Comment: I've updated with the example I really need. I tried to be too generic at first. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using regular expression:

```
m = /GeoLocation: \{"lng":(-?\d+\.\d+),"lat":(-?\d+\.\d+)\}/.match(html)
lng = m[1]
lat = m[2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

html

```
<h1>Hello World</h1>
<script type="text/javascript">var a;</script>
<script type="text/javascript" id="vars">var gmaps_vars = {"FullAddress": "Rio de Janeiro, Rio de Janeiro, Brasil", "GeoLocation": {"lng":-43.187554,"lat":-22.9470974}}</script>
```

js

```
$(function() {
    var coords = [];
    $.post(url, function(data, textStatus, jqxhr) {
        $.each($(data), function(index, value) {
            if ($(value).is("#vars")) {
              coords.push(JSON.parse($(value).text().replace(/var|gmaps_vars|\=/g, "")).GeoLocation);
              console.log(coords[0].lng + "\n" + coords[0].lat);
            };
        });
    });
});
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/HzPFg/